# SQL Oracle 'Invalid Identifier' and 'Table does not exist' Error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble identifying what is causing the following errors in my code:

```
    2   0.00    CREATE TABLE BRANCH ( BRANCH_ID NUMBER(3) , BRANCH_NAME VARC    ORA-00904: "LIBRARY_ID": invalid identifier  -
3   0.00    CREATE TABLE COPY ( BOOK_ID NUMBER(3) , BRACH_ID NUMBER(3) ,    ORA-00904: "BRANCH_ID": invalid identifier   -
4   0.00    CREATE TABLE PATRON ( PATRON_ID NUMBER(3) , FIRST_NAME VARCH    ORA-02263: need to specify the datatype for this column  -
5   0.01    CREATE TABLE CHECKOUT ( CHECKOUT_ID NUMBER(3) , COPY_ID NUMB    ORA-00942: table or view does not exist  -
6   0.00    CREATE TABLE WAITLIST ( BOOK_ID NUMBER(3) , PATRON_ID NUMBER    ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I cannot pinpoint where the lack of a datatype is or why my identifier is considered invalid. I am still learning and appreciate any help. Thank you guys in advance.  Here is my SQL code:

```
    CREATE TABLE LIBRARY_SYSTEM
( LIBRARY_ID NUMBER(3)
, LIBRARY_NAME VARCHAR2(50)
, STREET_ADDRESS VARCHAR2 (60)
, CITY VARCHAR2 (30)
, STATE CHAR (2)
, ZIPCODE NUMBER (5)
, PHONE NUMBER (10)
, MANAGER_NAME VARCHAR2(40)
, CONSTRAINT LIBARY_PK PRIMARY KEY (LIBRARY_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE BRANCH
( BRANCH_ID NUMBER(3)
, BRANCH_NAME VARCHAR2(50)
, STREET_ADDRESS VARCHAR2 (60)
, CITY VARCHAR2 (30)
, STATE CHAR (2)
, ZIPCODE NUMBER (5)
, PHONE NUMBER (10)
, BRANCH_MANAGER VARCHAR2(40)
, LIBARY_ID NUMBER(3)
, CONSTRAINT BRANCH_PK PRIMARY KEY (BRANCH_ID)
, CONSTRAINT BRANCH_LIBARY_FK FOREIGN KEY (LIBRARY_ID) REFERENCES LIBRARY_SYSTEM(LIBRARY_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE COPY
( BOOK_ID NUMBER(3)
, BRACH_ID NUMBER(3)
, CONSTRAINT COPY_BOOK_PK PRIMARY KEY (BOOK_ID, BRANCH_ID)
, CONSTRAINT COPY_BOOK_FK FOREIGN KEY (BOOK_ID) REFERENCES BOOK(BOOK_ID)
, CONSTRAINT COPY_BRANCH_FK FOREIGN KEY (BRANCH_ID) REFERENCES BRANCH(BRANCH_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PATRON
( PATRON_ID NUMBER(3)
, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(40)
, LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(40)
, STREET_ADDRESS VARCHAR2 (60)
, CITY VARCHAR2 (30)
, STATE CHAR (2)
, ZIPCODE NUMBER (5)
, PHONE NUMBER (10)
, FEE_BALANCE
, CONSTRAINT PATRON_PK PRIMARY KEY (PATRON_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CHECKOUT
( CHECKOUT_ID NUMBER(3)
, COPY_ID NUMBER(3)
, PATRON_ID NUMBER(3)
, OUT_DATE DATE
, DUE_DATE DATE
, RETURN_DATE DATE
, CONSTRAINT CHECKOUT_PK PRIMARY KEY (CHECKOUT_ID)
, CONSTRAINT CHECKOUT_COPY_FK FOREIGN KEY (COPY_ID) REFERENCES COPY(COPY_ID)
, CONSTRAINT CHECKOUT_PATRON_FK FOREIGN KEY (PATRON_ID) REFERENCES PATRON(PATRON_ID)
);   

CREATE TABLE WAITLIST
( BOOK_ID NUMBER(3)
, PATRON_ID NUMBER(3)
, BRANCH_ID NUMBER(3)
, ON_DATE DATE
, OFF_DATE DATE
, RETURN_DATE DATE
, CONSTRAINT COPY_BOOK_FK FOREIGN KEY (BOOK_ID) REFERENCES BOOK(BOOK_ID)
--, CONSTRAINT CHECKOUT_PATRON_FK FOREIGN KEY (PATRON_ID) REFERENCES PATRON(PATRON_ID)---
--, CONSTRAINT COPY_BRANCH_FK FOREIGN KEY (BRANCH_ID) REFERENCES BRANCH(BRANCH_ID)
); 

--sequences
CREATE SEQUENCE LIBRARY_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE BRANCH_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE PATRON_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;



--triggers
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERT_LIBRARY
BEFORE INSERT ON LIBRARY_SYSTEM
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  NEW_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT LIBRARY_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO NEW_ID FROM DUAL;
  :NEW.LIBRARY_ID := NEW_ID;
END;
/
COMMIT;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERT_BRANCH
BEFORE INSERT ON BRANCH
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  NEW_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT BRANCH_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO NEW_ID FROM DUAL;
  :NEW.BRANCH_ID := NEW_ID;
END;
/
COMMIT;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERT_PATRON
BEFORE INSERT ON PATRON
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  NEW_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT PATRON_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO NEW_ID FROM DUAL;
  :NEW.PATRON_ID := NEW_ID;
END;
/
COMMIT;
​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be just a few misspellings:

```
CREATE TABLE BRANCH
( BRANCH_ID NUMBER(3)
, BRANCH_NAME VARCHAR2(50)
, STREET_ADDRESS VARCHAR2 (60)
, CITY VARCHAR2 (30)
, STATE CHAR (2)
, ZIPCODE NUMBER (5)
, PHONE NUMBER (10)
, BRANCH_MANAGER VARCHAR2(40)
**, LIBARY_ID NUMBER(3)**
, CONSTRAINT BRANCH_PK PRIMARY KEY (BRANCH_ID)
, CONSTRAINT BRANCH_LIBARY_FK FOREIGN KEY (LIBRARY_ID) REFERENCES LIBRARY_SYSTEM(LIBRARY_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE COPY
( BOOK_ID NUMBER(3)
, **BRACH_ID** NUMBER(3)
, CONSTRAINT COPY_BOOK_PK PRIMARY KEY (BOOK_ID, BRANCH_ID)
, CONSTRAINT COPY_BOOK_FK FOREIGN KEY (BOOK_ID) REFERENCES BOOK(BOOK_ID)
, CONSTRAINT COPY_BRANCH_FK FOREIGN KEY (BRANCH_ID) REFERENCES BRANCH(BRANCH_ID)
);
```

Comment: And `patron.fee_balance` doesn't have a type; and `waitlist` is referencing a `book` table which doesn't seem to exist.